# Angular *ngSwitchCase is not executing

Tags: angular, ng-switch

I am new to Angular. I am using `ngSwitch` in my program but every time I run the program `*ngSwitchDefault` executes rather than `*ngSwitchCase`. Here is the code:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedControl" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let inputControl of inputArray; let i=index" 
    [value]="inputControl">{{inputArray[i]}}</option>                                  
</select>
<span [ngSwitch]="selectedControl">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="text">
    <p>text is selected</p>              
    </span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="radio">
    <p>radio is selected</p>
    </span>        
    <span *ngSwitchDefault>
    <p>Default value</p>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: You need to make it a string `"'true'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `*ngSwitchCase` expressions into the `''` to make them `strings`. The comparison will be used with `===`, so it will compare `string` with `string`. In your case it is going to find a member with name `radio` or `text` and get their values, which are undefined.

```
<span [ngSwitch]="selectedControl">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
    <!--                 ^----^ -->
    <p>text is selected</p>              
    </span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">
    <!--                 ^-----^ -->
    <p>radio is selected</p>
    </span>        
    <span *ngSwitchDefault>
    <p>Default value</p>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase `ngSwitchCase` expect `expression` not `string`. 
If you want to use hardcoded string replace `*ngSwitchCase="text"` with `*ngSwitchCase="'text'"`

Answer (score 0):

> Unlike JavaScript, which uses strict equality, Angular uses loose
>   equality. **This means that the empty string, "" matches 0.**

https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase

Comment: Answering with just a quote is usually a bit too brief. Please be so kind and add a sentence or two to relate the quote to the question.